# Trying to Detect a String Input after converting to Int32?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to allow the user to exit this game at any point by typing "quit". The issue that I have is that that the input field is initially being taken in as an Int, and when I try to convert it to a string it just breaks the game and exits.

I know that most people probably will tell me to change the variable input to a string and then convert it using TryParse but that would involve rewriting alot of code. I am not yet fully convinced that I can't achieve this result somehow with the code I have below but I need help!

Thanks!

```
using System;

namespace GuessingGame

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        GameStart();

  
        void GameStart()
        {

            bool match = false;

            int PlayerTwoGuesses = 5;
            int PlayerOneNumber;
            char confirm;
            int guess;

            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome To The Game!\n\n In this game, Player 1 will have to input an integer between 0 and 100.\n Player 2 will then have to guess to find the number!\n If Player 2 guesses correctly, Player 2 wins!\n Player 2 will have {PlayerTwoGuesses} chances to guess the correct number!\n If you ever want to quit the game, just type 'quit' at any prompt and press Enter\n.");

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();



            do
            {
                Console.Clear();


                Console.WriteLine("Player One - Please Enter A Number Between 0 and 100, and Press Enter!");
                PlayerOneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                string exit = "quit";

                if (PlayerOneNumber > 100)
                {
                    PlayerOneNumber = 100;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Number Will Be Changed To 100, since you entered a number higher than 100.");
                }
                else if (PlayerOneNumber < 0)
                {
                    PlayerOneNumber = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Number Will Be Changed To 0, since y entered a number low than 0.");
                    } else if (PlayerOneNumber.ToString() == exit) {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Are you sure you want {PlayerOneNumber} to be your number? Enter (Y/N)");
                confirm = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
            } while (confirm.Equals(Char.Parse("N")));

            Console.WriteLine($"Thanks, your number is {PlayerOneNumber}\nIt's time for Player 2 to guess!\nPlease Press Enter to Clear the Screen for Player 2!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Player Two - Guess the Number! You have {PlayerTwoGuesses} left!");
                guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (guess == PlayerOneNumber)
                {
                    match = true;
                    if (match)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Player 2 guessed that the number was {PlayerOneNumber}! Player 2 wins!");
                    }
                }
                else if (guess != PlayerOneNumber && guess > PlayerOneNumber)
                {
                    PlayerTwoGuesses--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong! Your Guess was TOO HIGH! Guess Again!");
                }
                else if (guess != PlayerOneNumber && guess < PlayerOneNumber)
                {
                    PlayerTwoGuesses--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong! Your Guess was TOO LOW! Guess Again!");
                }

                if (PlayerTwoGuesses <= 0)
                {
                    match = true;
                    Console.WriteLine($"You ran out of guesses! Player one wins!\nBy the way, the number was {PlayerOneNumber}");
                }
            } while (!match && PlayerTwoGuesses > 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Play Again...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            GameStart();



        }
     


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` gives you a string. You don't need to convert anything to check for a quit.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the input first and check if they entered "quit". If they did, exit the game. If not, continue on with converting it to a number or whatever else you want to do with the input:

```
Console.Write("Player One: Enter a number from 0 to 100 and press enter: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input.Equals("quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // Quit the game or whatever you want when they enter 'quit'
}
else if (!int.TryParse(input, out PlayerOneNumber))
{
    // Give a message or restart the input process if they didn't enter a valid number
}
else
{
    // If we get this far, they didn't enter 'quit' and they did enter a valid number
    // which has been assigned to 'PlayerOneNumber'. Now we can do the other validation
    // that the number is in the proper range.
}
```

I know you're just beginning, but your code makes a lot of assumptions on what the user enters. It's usually a good idea to follow the above pattern in order to ensure their input is valid and then give them the proper feedback if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
string InputString = Console.ReadLine();
if(exit == InputString)
{//Exit code}
PlayerOneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(InputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert `"quit"` to an int using `Convert.ToInt32`, nor with `int.Parse`; even if you could, there would be no way to convert the integer back into the string "quit". You would have to create your own method that accepts special cases, but I strongly recommend you don't do that.

Use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) instead. If it returns false, check for your exit condition:

```cs
var line = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse(line, out int guess) {
    if (line.Equals("quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        return; // Run exit game logic here.
    }
}
// Continue with game normally
```

Not part of your question, but using `TryParse` also helps prevent exceptions. Program as if you don't trust users to use your app as intended: for example, you might add in a console message and a `continue` if the user gives an input that can't be parsed to an int and isn't a command (like 'quit').